# CSS - what is @page?

Tags: css

I have this in my stylesheet:

```
@page 
{
    margin: 0.5in;
    padding: 1em;

    @bottom-right 
    {
        content: counter(page);
        font-family: ConfluenceInstalledFont, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 8pt;
    }

    @bottom-left
    {
        content: "Some text";
        font-family: ConfluenceInstalledFont, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 8pt;
    }
}
```

---

What is @page and what more can I do with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[@page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-box) sets styles for paged media. [This gives the intro](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-intro) to what paged media is, but as far as I've ever seen it used, it's pretty much only necessary when you want to control the printing of a page.

The [description from w3 for @page under CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-box-page-rule) has a little better description but naturally only applies to css3.

Answer (score 3):

With the [`@page` rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) you can specify the properties of a printable page. You can add a margin or define a per-page footer that the `@bottom-right` and `@bottom-left` rules do in your stylesheet.